# Repeating a function X amount of times while returning a value

Tags: javascript, loops, repeat

I have a code that takes in a user input of an integer "X" and then repeats it `Math.ceil(X/3)` amount of times, so I used this. Let "X" be 10 in this example

```js
function repeat(func, times) {
 func();
 --times && repeat(func, times);
}
function test() {
 console.log('test');
}

repeat(function() { test(); }, Math.ceil(10 / 3));
```

I would like to tweak this a bit so that the code would return the value of how much "X" was subtracted by until it reaches 0, but if the final value is negative it would return the "X" amount left itself. Sorry if that sounded confusing, Here's what I mean to further clarify what I'm aiming for:

```
/* The user inputs X as 10
I would like the ouput to look like this: */
"test 3" //10-3=7 so 7 left, return 3 to output
"test 3" //7-3=4 so 4 left, return 3 to output
"test 3" //4-3=1 so 0 left, return 3 to output
"test 1" //1-3=-2 would be less than 0, so do 1-1 instead and that results to 0, return 1 to output and end loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **pass the actual numbers to `repeat`** rather than just a result of `10/3`, since it will not know otherwise when to stop.

**Demo**

```js
function repeat(func, num1, num2 ) 
{
  num1 > num2 ? func(num2) : func(num1);
  if ( num1 > num2 )
  {
     num1 -= num2;
     repeat(func, num1, num2);
  }
}

function test(times) {
  console.log('test', times)
}

repeat(test, 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please briefly explain what this line does? `num1 > num2 ? func(num2) : func(num1);`

Comment: @newbie It just means that after `4-3`, `num1` will be `1` and `num2` will stay `3`, and since num1 is now lesser than num2, num1 should be displayed instead of num2.

Comment: Ah I understand. Thanks again :)